# javascript object loading content into DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i'm trying to figure out if my code is making my page load forever or if its iterating continuously through my javascript object. I have an object with 46 entries of which 46 images, which also act as modal triggers, should be loaded automatically once the page loads. The page is loading half of the images and isn't loading the rest. file size of the images is minimal, at most 97kb. the videos that are linked in the object do go up to 9mb, but i'm under the assumption that they aren't being loaded until the click event is fired. I am correct? Should i be using ajax to load the video content? or is my javascript code the culprit? I'm trying to learn as much as possible, so any ideas/advice are welcomed and greatly appreciated!

[live site](http://reneinla.com/kris/) | [fiddle with same code](https://jsfiddle.net/renevilla23/1edf7skt/31/)

**JavaScript**

```
var dataCollection = {
  'videoData': [
    {
      'id'      : 0,
      'title'   : 'Badminton',
      'company' : 'Pepto Bismol',
      'gifLink' : 'http://reneinla.com/kris/gifs/BadmintonPeptoBismolCommercial.gif',
      'srcMp4'  : 'http://reneinla.com/kris/videos/BadmintonPeptoBismolCommercial.mp4',
      'srcWebm' : 'http://reneinla.com/kris/videos/BadmintonPeptoBismolCommercial.webm',
      'srcOgv'  : 'http://reneinla.com/kris/videos/BadmintonPeptoBismolCommercial.ogv',
      'poster'  : 'http://reneinla.com/kris/videos/BadmintonPeptoBismolCommercial.jpg'
      },
      { ...
     ]
    };

var videos = $('#video');
var modalContent = $('#video-modal');

var appendVideo = function(videoObj) {
  var poster = videoObj.poster;
  var srcMp4 = videoObj.srcMp4;
  var srcWebm = videoObj.srcWebm;
  var srcOgv = videoObj.srcOgv;
  var video = $('<div class="video col-sm-12 col-md-3"><img src="' + poster + '" data-title="' + videoObj.title + '" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"/></div>');

  var videoPlayer = $('<video preload="auto" controls><source src="' + srcMp4 + '" type="video/mp4;"><source src="' + srcWebm + '" type="video/webm;"><source src="' + srcOgv + '" type="video/ogv;"></video>');
  videos.append(video);

video.find('img').click(function(e) {
  modalContent.append(videoPlayer);
  // debug
  // alert(videoObj.srcMp4);
  // console.log(videoObj.srcMp4);
});

$('#myModal, .close').on('click', function(){
  modalContent.find('video').remove();
});

$('.myHTMLvideo').click(function() {
    $(this).get(0).paused ? $(this).get(0).play() : $(this).get(0).pause();
  });
};

for (var i = 0; i < dataCollection.videoData.length; i++) {
  var obj = dataCollection.videoData[i];
    appendVideo(obj);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container row">
  <div id="video"></div>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <div class="modal-body" id="video-modal"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you try removing `preload="auto"`? The Fiddle seems to work fine, but that might be because you only included 3 elements there.

Comment: i think its because it only has 3 elements. i updated the live site, but its still loading...the browser window at the bottom says "processing request..."

Comment: I checked the live site with the network tab open for Chrome dev tools, and the mp4 files definitely are being downloaded even if you don't click the images.

Comment: Try `video preload="none"`

Comment: @MarkWade - that worked! i was assuming that if you didnt include it, it wouldnt load the videos...lesson learned! thanks again!

Comment: I have noticed that your “×” (close) buttons have 46 close events attached _each_ that all have the same function because of this part of your script: `$('#myModal, .close').on('click', function () {b.find('video').remove()})`.

Comment: @Xufox - can you please show me how you noticed the 46 events attached  to the x(close)? Is there an alternative to write that script so that it doesnt create 46 events?

Comment: Inspect element → click on little [“ev”](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_event_listeners) box. Just run the `on` script _once_. Currently it’s in the loop that inserts the videos into the page. Or try `$('#myModal, .close').last().on…` to attach the event only to the last (newly generated) one.

Comment: thanks for the insight on the inspect element, didnt know about this feature. i updated my code to reflect the suggestion you made but its still show 46 events...

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
var videoPlayer = $('<video preload="none" controls><source src="' + srcMp4 + '" type="video/mp4;"><source src="' + srcWebm + '" type="video/webm;"><source src="' + srcOgv + '" type="video/ogv;"></video>');
```